# Having trouble authenticating users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a lot of trouble with the `$_SESSION` variable. I'm trying to create a way for users to log in and out. I can log a user in but i don't seem to be able to maintain the session when i switch page. When the user correctly logs in they are taken to `profile.php`. But if i return to `index.php` the following error is printed:

`Notice: Undefined index: login in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/Shared sites/userlogreg/index.php on line 3`

I'm quite new to this but from looking on SO and elsewhere i can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['login'] == 1) {
    echo "<h1>Logged in!</h1>"; 
} else {
    echo "<h1>Not logged in</h1><br/>";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="emailSignIn">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="passwordSignIn">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in" />
    </form> 

    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="firstnameRegister">First name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lastnameRegister">Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="emailRegister">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="passwordRegister">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create account" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

$email = sanitize_input($_POST['email']); //echo "Sanitized email: ".$email; echo "<br/>";
$password = $_POST['password']; //echo "Inputted password: ".$password; echo "<br/>";

if ((!isset($email)) || (!isset($password))) {
    // VISITOR NEEDS TO ENTER AN EMAIL AND PASSWORD
    //echo "Data not provided";
} else {
    // CONNECT TO MYSQL
    $mysql = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    if(!$mysql) {
    //echo "Cannot connect to PHPMyAdmin.";
    exit;
    } else {

    }
}
// SELECT THE APPROPRIATE DATABASE
$selected = mysqli_select_db($mysql, "languageapp");
if(!$selected) {
    //echo "Cannot select database.";
    exit;
} else {

}

// GET THE USER'S UNIQUE SALT FROM THE DATABASE
$unique_salt = mysqli_query($mysql, "select uniqueSalt from user where email = '".$email."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($unique_salt);
//echo "Salt: ".$row['uniqueSalt']; echo "<br/>";

// HASH THE PASSWORD 
$iterations = 10;
$hashed_password = crypt($password,$row['uniqueSalt']); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; ++$i)
{
    $hashed_password = crypt($hashed_password . $password,$row['uniqueSalt']);
}

//echo "Password entered by user: ".$hashed_password; echo "<br/>";

$user_db_password = mysqli_query($mysql, "select password from user where email = '".$email."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_db_password);
//echo "User's password: ".$row['password']; echo "<br/>";

// query the database to see if there is a record which matches
$query = "select count(*) from user where email = '".$email."' and password = '".$hashed_password."'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query);
if(!$result) {
    //echo "Cannot run query.";
    exit;
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];

if ($count > 0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['errors'] = "";
    header("location:profile.php");
    //echo "<h1>Login successful!</h1>";
    //echo "<p>Welcome.</p>";
    //echo "<p>This page is only visible when the correct details are provided.</p>";
} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = '';
    header("location:index.php");
    //echo "<h1>Login unsuccessful!</h1>";
    //echo "<p>The email and password combination entered was not recognized</p>";
}

// CLEAN THE INPUT
function sanitize_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: I also had trouble finding info on this a few weeks ago when I was looking for the same thing, but i did find it eventually on someone's blog.

Comment: You're on the right track using `mysqli` but you are using it wrong. `sanitize_input` is **NOT** a substitute for using proper placeholders in your SQL queries. You should **never** use `$` vars directly, but `?` placeholders instead.

Comment: @tadman Could you explain this to me? Is the idea being not change the user's input but to instead alter a duplicate (placeholder) of the data? Perhaps you could direct me to some information on it. Thanks.

Comment: Placeholders show up as `?` and are a hint to the database driver to encode whatever value is bound to that position using the correct escaping. Numbers and strings are usually handled differently. You don't have to do anything special. There are many examples [on Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/php) which help explain better. If you use placeholders properly you can correctly handle any kind of data without bugs or security risks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if ($_SESSION['login'] == 1) {
```

..to this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == 1) {
```

That way, you check if `'login'` is set before you access it.

Comment: Brilliant! It was that easy - i was afraid i'd done something drastically wrong. Thanks

Comment: @garethdn If the answer helped, don't forget to mark it correct! :)